LWC ShowToastEvent Undefined
handleSubscribe() {
    const messageCallback = function (response) {
        console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));

        this.identifier = response.data.payload.Asset_Identifier__c;
        this.status = response.data.payload.Disconnected__c;

        if (this.status) {
            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                  variant: "success",
                  title: "Ready to receive notifications"
                })
              );
        } else {
            this.showErrorToast();
        }
    };

I'm trying to run this code after suscribe to a platform event, this works, I'm receiving data, but when I'm trying to show a simple toast I can see "this.dispatchEvent" is undefined, toasts works on this class, I've placed one on the connectedCallback and works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Found the solution in this answer.
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/319540/dispatch-event-or-apex-call-is-not-working-in-lwc-callback Thanks.
